# How to get all running apps with user interface?

Tags: android, background-process

I am trying to get just the number of running apps that are with UI programmatically.  All I found is the number of all running apps with ActivityManager.

```
ActivityManager actvityManager = (ActivityManager)
this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = actvityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
```

but this is a list of all background procceses. I need list of apps from Task Manager.(long press home button, but just number of apps)

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which Android version you are using, but try this:
At Home Screen, go to Settings, choose App Settings

Comment: Sorry, I mean programmatically